# Pulling Google Analytics Multi Channel Funnel data via API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to pull the multi-channel funnel reports from the Google Analytics API and am getting the following error:

**Invalid value 'mcf:source'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(ga:.+)?'**

Here is the code I am using, it works fine when the dimensions & metrics are from the ga:... family, but for some reason it won't let me pull mcf: reports.

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$analytics_id   = 'ga:XXXXXXXX';
$lastWeek       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-26 day', time()));
$today          = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-26 day', time()));

try {
    $optParams = array();
    $optParams['dimensions'] = "mcf:source";
    #$optParams['sort'] = "";
    $optParams['max-results'] = "10000";
    $metrics = 'mcf:totalConversions';
    $results = $analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id,
                       $lastWeek,
                       $today,$metrics,$optParams);

    $rows = $results->getRows();
    foreach ($results->columnHeaders as $header) {
        $headerName = ucwords(preg_replace('/(\w+)([A-Z])/U', '\\1 \\2', str_replace('ga:', '', $header->name)));
        printf('%s', $headerName);
        print ',';
    }

    print "\n";

    foreach ($results->rows as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            printf('%s', $cell);
            print ',';
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the top of my head I'd say it's because your are using `$analytics->data_ga->get()` instead of `$analytics->data_mcf->get()` (Multichannel data has it's own API).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, after changing the script runs okay but now my file is blank, literally 10000 blank rows.. any idea why this is occurring?