# "Google MC Funnels API" for PHP (simple query) not working

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to put this [Google funnels API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/mcfLibraries) to work in my php server, just like [Gapi](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide), but I can't understand how to write the new queries.

1. The downloaded example is not working. I am not getting any data back!
2. I study the `.php` sample files in the "examples" folder contained in that API. However, they are very different from the original "Gapi".

So far there are no examples to work from. Every step to authorize my API to work seems to be OK, but I don't know how to verify this. How do I check that this API is OK on my php server? If it is, how does one create a simple query with this "MC funnels API"?

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using currently?   The MFC API is tricky I will try and help.   I don't have any PHP examples of its usage but I may still be able to help you get it working.

Comment: [code is Here](http://senacomputer.jp/clients/temp/simple-query.php.txt)  and the API can be [download here ](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/mcfLibraries), but, this example... do not work like Core API, (like ga:pageviews) ....  I prefere to work in the same way (like get data with mcf:totalConversionValue).  [Google's referer ](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/analytics/v3/analytics.data.mcf.get?ids=ga%253A80456636&start-date=2015-10-01&end-date=2015-11-01metrics=mcf%253AtotalConversionValue&_h=2&)  hope i give all info you need!

Tks again!

Comment: MFC doesn't return data like the core reporting api.  a lot of the columns are MCF_SEQUENCE which isn't just one value it returns a Json string of the sequence that you have to pick apart manually

Comment: You cant edit comments unfortunately.  If you run across any issues with the tutorials or documentation let me know.  I can ping the team and have them corrected for the next person.   If you get any errors edit your question and add the code.

Comment: Ok, trying again: API can be [download here](http://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/) and the code i try [is here](http://senacomputer.jp/clients/temp/simple-query.php.zip), Thanks Again!

Comment: In response to question **How to create one simple query with this "MC funnels API" ?**  i maybe find some useful in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597137/pulling-google-analytics-multi-channel-funnel-data-via-api), but still don't know how to "authenticate" my API... so, yet, no data !

Comment: if its your data go with a service account https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php just make sure to add the service account email address as a user at the account level in the admin section of the google analytics website.

Comment: Sorry.. I dont get it... **1)**  when i use this example "examples/service-account.php", it ask me for a key?!?!? (with one? example = 60741128830-8qv7ssaemepf1qau9us0ktnav5408h1m.apps.googleusercontent.com ?? )  **2)** and  to put the json file in the correct folder... but it say "Invalid client secret JSON file" ?!?!  **3)** and about the echo pageHeader("Service Account Access");  what to put here? i tryied several combinations... ** sorry **..i think i missing something...

Comment: that code is for service account.  you need to create service account credentials.   json file is for Oauth2

Comment: I think thats probably a good idea.  The only thing i have just shows access to Measurement api. http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Comment: and all the time I was thinking in **OAuth2.0**... OK next question, how to set up my local PHP API, with "service account" key? I looked for info, but not success.