# Google MC Funnels - Service account credentials?

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

There are two different types keys for " [Service account credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/serviceaccount?project=kamialine-1042) " **JSON** and **P12**

Please, which one is indicated to work with "Google MC Funnels API"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either can be used with MFC API.   Service account credentials and Oauth2 credentials have nothing to do with the which API you can access.  Except with regard to some APIs which don't support service accounts (YouTube API , and blogger to name two).   Service account and Oauth2 are all about gaining access to the data you need.

**Service account p12 file**

Service accounts are used to access data you the developer have access to. If you want to grant someone else access to see your Google Analyitcs data you would use a service account.   Setup will require that you take the service account email address and add it as a user at the account level in the google analytics website admin section. it must be the account level.

**Oauth authentication Json file**

Oauth2 will request a user give your application permission to access their data.

Comment: I just.... want to make queries like [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597137/pulling-google-analytics-multi-channel-funnel-data-via-api). where, I put metrics and dimentitons and receive one arrey of data. Wich one I should pick? p12 ou json?

Comment: It doesn't matter you can use either.  The Question is is that data you want to access do you have access to the Google Analytics account if so then go with a service account.   If you want me to run your application so I can access my data then go with Oauth2.